# JavaFX Using multiple Images form A folder

Tags: javafx

I am creating a small image matching game for a project in JavaFX.I have created a 6x6 grid and I have it working for a single image.(all 36 squares have the same image,i wanted to test if the matching works first and it does)
My difficulty is using the rest 17 png images I have in a res folder.They all have a different name matching  the content of the image(horse.png,apple.png etc) as is required and everything works except using every image from the folder.
This is where I fill the game squares with the image:

`

```
     InputStream input = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/res/apple.png");

     Image image = new Image((input),90,90,true,true);



    List<Tile> tiles = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_OF_PAIRS; i++) {
        tiles.add(new Tile(image));
        tiles.add(new Tile(image));
        input=getClass().getResourceAsStream("/res/apple.png");

        image=new Image((input),90,90,true,true);


    }`
```

Comment: Finding every resource matching a specific pattern in the classpath usually is difficult. This leaves you with 2 options: 1. create some data structure containing the necessary info to compute the image paths (e.g. `new String[] {"apple", "horse", ...}`) 2. change the image names in a way that allows you to easily compute the paths, e.g. `/res/image1.png`, `/res/.image2.png`, ... (After all it should not matter what is displayed but if the images clicked match which can be determined regardless of the image names.)

Comment: I will propably try something along the lines of the first suggestion,it is requiered that tha name of the images match the content of the image